# Set file as modified using OTA

Tags: delphi, ota

As we know Build compiles all used units and Compile compiles only changed used units. But when you are working with ifdefs and need to change it a lot of times you must Build the project a lot of times.
If you have to much libraries that you know that this IFDEF will not change the behavior, there is no reason to build this library again.

What I want to do discovery is a way to say to the IDE that some files was changed and call the Compile and not the Build.

How to get the units and every else I know, but some know how to set the unit as modified?

Tks

---

Couldn't find a why to solve my problem yet. I found a way to set it as modified the problem is that it doesn't force the IDE to build it as I thought it'll.
Some one know what checks is made to an archive be sent to compile ?

Comment: Did you try changing ("touching")  the file date time on disk?

Comment: Yes, I do. What happens, if I minimize the IDE and after maximize the IDE asks if that the files were modified and ask if I'd like to reopen this. If I say I want, in next compile these unit will be recompiled. But if I didn't do it, it doesn't work :/ Any idea let me know, I test and post here the result. Tks

Comment: Huh?  I didn't understand what you are asking here.  Your update means that you are starting to realize what I said: "You can see perhaps that this is more complex than you first thought." Perhaps what you wish to do is not exactly possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in a simpler way. I just deleted the DCU of the file and ok, it'll compile it again. :D
http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/KCB9cq2Z8c

Comment: Much better solution, I think. If the DCu doesn't exist, the timestamp no longer matters. You could also back-date the DCU file to last-year. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that what you want is to mark editor buffers modified.  That assumes there is an editor buffer to modify, which in most cases, there isn't, for most items in your Project. Let's suppose that you ALWAYS have every file in your project open at all times, then perhaps you can tweak those open units, this way.

My thinking is that you would actually need not only to mark editor buffers modified, but also TOUCH all the files on disk that would need to be rebuilt because of the #define change.

To know which files are affected, you would need to read all the files.  I think, that the odds of you doing this reliably, over and over again, and faster than just doing a BUILD are pretty slim.

But if you did decide to go for it, you need not only to modify buffer Modified flags, but also, for any other file in the current project group, or which is in a folder included in the search or library path, find any file which might be affected.

You can see perhaps that this is more complex than you first thought.

And, as far as OTA goes, here is IOTAEditor property, Modified, it is read only.

The OTA doesn't want you changing it:

```
IOTAEditor = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{F17A7BD0-E07D-11D1-AB0B-00C04FB16FB3}']
    ...
    function GetModified: Boolean;
    ..
    property Modified: Boolean read GetModified;
    ..
  end;
```

But you could actually modify the buffer CONTENT itself, and that would set the flag.

Use IOTAEditorContent, get the content (IStream), modify it (add a space), then modify it again (take away the space).  You have now set the dirty bit (call GetModified just for luck).

I found some sample code from JCL JclStackTraceViewerStackCodeUtils.pas that shows you how to read editor content using IOTAEditorContent:

```
function GetFileEditorContent(const AFileName: string): IStream;
var
      I: Integer;
      Module: IOTAModule;
      EditorContent: IOTAEditorContent;
begin
      Result := nil;
      Module := (BorlandIDEServices as IOTAModuleServices).FindModule(AFileName);
      if Assigned(Module) then
      begin
        for I := 0 to Module.ModuleFileCount - 1 do
          if Supports(Module.ModuleFileEditors[I], IOTAEditorContent, EditorContent) then
          begin
            Result := EditorContent.Content;
            Break;
          end;
      end;
end;
```

After re-reading your question, it seems to me you only want to mark open editor buffers as all changed, and then do a compile, for speed.   So you might want to do this: Take the code above, get the IOTAEditorContent using Supports(), and tweak each one.

Update: Short and sweet version: Modifying the buffer isn't sufficient. Plus, you won't have buffers for the files you need to change, plus Touching the file on the disk doesn't do what you want. So no, you can't do exactly what you wanted to do.  And even if you could somehow modify the compiler's ability to do Make-style dependency and modification checks, you would probably cause a lot of problems inside the IDE.

Comment: Tks, I'll test it tomorrow and post the results.

Comment: Warren P, about your answer 'The OTA doesn't want you changing it:', I found an alternative to it. On interface IOTAModule70, I can set the archive as modified without problems, and I don't need to get any buffer to this. Here is the code I used to it http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/4zoAGrEx3h, if you'd like to take a look in all code let me know I post it here. 
Ok, but, setting it as modified was not enough to do what I want as I though it'll.

Comment: Then I found the other problems as you can check on my answers, the solution to solve my particular problem is intercept the compile and remove the Dcu's that I need to be recompile, in my case it solve my problem 'cause I have about 13 unit that must be recompile almost all the time and 702 that must not, so it's much faster now. But I'll search to other alternatives to make it as I wish.

Answer (score -1):

On IOTAModule70 = interface(IOTAModule50) I'll find MarkModified:
Description: 
 { MarkModifed will mark this module as "modified" without actually indicating
      *why* is it modified (which will cause internal file dates to remain constant).
      This *will* force the IDE to ask to save this module when the user attempts
      to close it.  It will also clear the "discardability" of a new unnamed
      module such as when File|New|Application is selected. }

Comment: -1, read carefully the [@Warren answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504574/set-file-as-modified-using-ota/5505491#5505491).  This will work only if there's a editor buffer to mark as modified.

Comment: In my case I want to change my files, these ifdefs are particulars.

Comment: Other thing, could not change the comment above. 
Did you tested it ? 
That affirmation was not valid, I can set modified without the unit open by my ide. Check the code and make your testes.
http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/4zoAGrEx3h

Comment: OTHER thing, to check that it was modified remove line 15 and open a file on IDE.

Comment: Excuse, I forgot to add the GetCurrentProject function. http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/ThoHcufVnv